# compare function not working in a rock paper scissor programm

Tags: javascript

i mad a rockpaperscissors program (the code below) that logs user input, cmoputer choice and then compares to get the result. the comparing part doesn't work for some reason it always logs "It's a tie", can someone help.

the code:

````
  let playerSelection = choice();
  function choice(){
    let input = prompt("pick either rock,paper or scissors");
    console.log(input.toLowerCase());
  }

  let computerChoice = computerPlay();
  function computerPlay(){
    let picks =["rock","paper","scissors"];
    let pick = picks[Math.floor(Math.random(picks)*picks.length)];
    console.log (pick);
  }

  function compare(playerSelection, computerChoice){
    if(playerSelection === computerChoice){
      console.log("It's a tie!")
    }
    else if((playerSelection == "rock" && computerChoice == "scissors")||
       (playerSelection == "paper" && computerChoice == "rock")||
       (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerChoice == "paper")){
      console.log("you win! computer lose.");
    }
    else{
      console.log("computer win! you lose.");
    }
  }
  compare();
}

function game(){
  console.log(playRound());
}

game();```
````

Comment: If you always call `compare` with no arguments (like right after your function definition), you compare undefined to undefined, which is `true`

Comment: Your functions are not returning anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `playerSelection` and `computerChoice` to the `compare` function as parameters when you call the function:

```
compare(playerSelection, computerChoice);
```

Also you should return values from the `choice()`and `computerPlay()`function in order to have values assigned to player and computer. Example for computerPlay:

```
 function computerPlay(){
    let picks =["rock","paper","scissors"];
    let pick = picks[Math.floor(Math.random(picks)*picks.length)];
    return pick;
 }
```

Here is a full snippet:

```js
  let playerSelection = choice();

  function choice(){
    let input = prompt("pick either rock,paper or scissors");
    return input;
  }

  let computerChoice = computerPlay();

  function computerPlay(){
    let picks =["rock","paper","scissors"];
    let pick = picks[Math.floor(Math.random(picks)*picks.length)];
    return pick;
  }

  function compare(playerSelection, computerChoice){
    if(playerSelection === computerChoice){
      console.log("It's a tie!")
    }
    else if((playerSelection == "rock" && computerChoice == "scissors")||
       (playerSelection == "paper" && computerChoice == "rock")||
       (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerChoice == "paper")){
      console.log("you win! computer lose.");
    }
    else{
      console.log("computer win! you lose. ");
    }
  }
  compare(playerSelection, computerChoice);
```